# css aligning listed blocks

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a navigation menu for a simple html/css site, it uses blocks and unorganized lists to add items to the navigation.

The problem is that I want my navigation to be centered, right now it floats from left to right, is there another way of aligning the listed div other than making it float right?  I tried using left:20; but didn't work, here is the code.

As I say, just need that to center slightly to the right, I am making it float to the left so that it organizes the list properly, without it, it'd be a messy list, try it and you'll see what I mean...  Thanks for help! :D

```css
body {  
 font-family: Arial;
}

#nav { /*indexed so I can see it over a content div.*/
 z-index:0; 
}

ul {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
}

ul li {
 float: left; 
 width: 8%; 
 height: 40px; 
 background-color: #000000;
 opacity: 0.8; 
 line-height: 40px; 
 text-align: center; 
 font-size: 90%; 
}

ul li a {
 text-decoration: none; 
 color: white;
 display: block;
}

ul li a:hover {
 background-color: green;
}

ul li ul li{
 display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
 display: block;
 margin-left: 0%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Attractions</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Our Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Camp Sites</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Mission &amp; Vision</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Resources</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Plan Visit</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Activities</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Parks</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Shops</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Birthdays</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Map</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Directions</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean having the nav div completely centered on the screen?

Comment: Background and middle div position and scale as they should, done a simple linear gradient background from w3schools but want my div to contain the nav bar, here is the image of what I am aiming for: https://i.imgur.com/pvqt1bm.png

Answer (score 0):

This, I think, gives the nicest result:

```
#nav {
    left:40%
    position:relative;
}
```

When using float, be careful using it without a clearfix hack. A float could end up collapsing your entire site. Link for it here, also an explanation: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp

Comment: Thanks, worked well, but is there a way to also move the div down the page?  tried top:5% but no luck

Comment: ^Can't edit last comment, but your solution also leaves a big space to the right :/ can't see where I've went wrong...  Code is the same, seems to be a problem with the width, but the width looks fine to me....  Also it moves around when screen is shrunk, is there  way to keep it fixed but move it as if it was relative...  maybe I could put it in a div that was positioned right...  Either way, there's a big space at the right and it doesn't like resizing